# Writing the test result to the Excel -nunit

Tags: c#, nunit

Is it possible to write the test result to a excel like pass or fail using nunit and C# . If any example can be provided it would be great .

Answer (score 1):

With [nunit-console](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2) you can export test run results to XML and specify XSLT transform. With XSLT transform you can, for example, [convert XML to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt) and then use Excel to do whatever you want to do with test run results in CSV.

Comment: Thank u , completely lost when it come to nunit-console command , I know i have to run this command "nunit-console /transform:myTransform.xslt nunit.tests.dll" i get the following error  "fatal error: invalid arrgument:/transform:myTransform.xslt"

Comment: It seems like this option was deprecated in Nunit 2.6. But you can still use [external XSLT processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297282/apply-xslt-to-an-xml-file)