# SharePoint XML Visualization

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint, reporting-services, web-parts

I have a SharePoint document library with about 40 XML files of the same datatype. 
I would like to visualize the contained data within SharePoint.

The requirement is that I click on a button next to the XML file and get a graphically rendered HTML page. (or something like that) ;-)

There are probably several options here.

- I could write an XSLT and "somehow" link it to the XML Viewer Web Part with the selected XML?
- Implement a separte page like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297282/apply-xslt-to-an-xml-file)? How in SharePoint?
- Maybe I could also use the SSRS? But how can a dynamic XML source be used ...?
- ...

Do you have any ideas? 
How would you implement that?

Comment: What have you tried till now? Do share

Comment: I have already wrote a XSLT file that renders the xml data in a "customer friendly" way und added it to the library. Than I've created a new Webpart-Page and added a XML Viewer WepPart with a static XML and XSL URL. The problem is that it works very good for this one XML but not dynamicly from the list with every XML as source.

Comment: Perhaps you should post this to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236178/sharepoint-xml-visualization