# using php to style xml alphabetically on client side with xsl

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I'm using PHP to query a list of people in a chat room and then appending to XML so the AJAX script on the client side can grab it. I don't want to put too much stress on the server having order it alphabetical by name.  therefore; I'm thinking of using xslt on the client side to order it. But I'm not sure how to attach it to the XML page, and when I do, I keep getting errors. :/
so can someone show me how to properly do it.

php:

```
header('Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli_connect, "UTF8");

$xml = new DomDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$root = $xml->createElement('root');
$xml->appendChild($root);
    $message = $xml->createElement('message');
    $root->appendChild($message);  

//while loop and appending the result from query

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Result:

```
  <root>
        <message>
            <name>foo</name>
            <gender>1</gender>
            <chat_message>hello world</chat_message>
        </message>
        <message>
            <name>boo</name>
            <gender>1</gender>
            <chat_message>Hello</chat_message>
        </message>
    </root>
```

I need the XML to sort it in alphabetical order by name like this:

```
<root>
    <message>
        <name>boo</name>
        <gender>1</gender>
        <chat_message>Hello</chat_message>
    </message>
    <message>
        <name>foo</name>
        <gender>1</gender>
        <chat_message>hello world</chat_message>
    </message>
</root>
```

Update:
Tried to append xslt on the php page but I keep geting an error:
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed.

```
$xslt = $xml->createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"');
$xml->appendChild($xslt);
```

Comment: you should just use json tbh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using PHP's [XSLT processor class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php) (might require enabling the xsl extension) where you can apply an embedded XSLT using [`<xsl:sort>`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp) on the `message/name` value.

```
...
$xslstr = '<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
           <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
            <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

             <xsl:template match="root">
                <root>        
                   <xsl:for-each select="message">
                      <xsl:sort select="name"/>
                      <message>           
                          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                      </message>
                   </xsl:for-each>
                </root>
             </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>';

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->loadXML($xslstr);

// Configure transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// Transform XML source
$newXML = new DOMDocument;
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// Output New XML content
echo $newXML;
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <message>
    <name>boo</name>
    <gender>1</gender>
    <chat_message>Hello</chat_message>
  </message>
  <message>
    <name>foo</name>
    <gender>1</gender>
    <chat_message>hello world</chat_message>
  </message>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank Parfait. (: Just a question: in this method, will the XSL process on the client computer or server? Also, how do I import the Style Sheet from a file instead of a variable. If that possible?

Comment: PHP is server-sided language, so code runs on server. You could add an [xslt stylesheet line to xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456697/how-to-link-up-xml-file-with-xslt-file) and client browser will process it. But example has no styling just markup. To read from file, save XSLT as .xsl file and instead of `loadXML(string)`, use `load(filepath)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier way to do it..

```
// convert xml to native array
$array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlstring)),TRUE);

// add stuff to it..
$array['something'] = 'something';

// do whatever sorting..
asort($array);

// convert back to xml..
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Thanks! But all that is still done on the server side, right?

Comment: yes, you didn't mention wanting it to be clinet side.

Comment: I did, it's in the question. XD That what xslt can do I believe...:/

Comment: My bad I missed that part of the question. I had never heard of xslt before I read this but I skimmed thru the Wikipedia page and it sorta just looks like a stylesheet language.. I may be wrong.. but either way this would be a lot easier on client side if you switch to json which doesn't require a bunch of 3rd party software to use..

Comment: yup, xslt is like css to html...I think. I like to use json, but xml is much faster. it use less of the user resource, especially when my javascript has alot of  AJAX settime loops. (: