# Trying to convert XML into an HTML table

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm not very familiar with XML (and have never used XSL sheets at all), but have been tasked with using it to transfer output to a webpage. I've read up on several of the XML to HTML questions posed here and tutorials on W3S, and have something down for an XSL stylesheet.

Basically, I want the final HTML to print out two tables, one showing the various Arena values, and a second table showing the singular Flag value.

XML sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stadium>
  <Arena>
    <Team>Team1</Team>
    <Field>Arena1</Field>
    <Score>100</Score>
  </Arena>
  <Arena>
    <Team>Team2</Team>
    <Field>Arena1</Field>
    <Score>100</Score>
  </Arena>
  <Arena>
    <Team>Team3</Team>
    <Field>Arena2</Field>
    <Score>100</Score>
  </Arena>
  <Flag>
    <Team>Team3</Team>
  </Flag>
</Stadium>
```

XSL sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>Field</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="Stadium/Arena">

                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Team" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Field" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Score" /></td>
                </tr>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Team</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="Stadium/Flag">

                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Team" /></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is my current output:

```
Team Stadium Points Team /* Google Docs Dark UI by UGoBoom */ /* Version 1.0 */ /* Published Oct 26 2015 */ /* Aesthetic inspired by Vertex-gtk theme */ @namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
```

So clearly, the XSL isn't communicating with the XML properly. Can anyone explain what else I need to do with my XSL stylesheet to print out a proper table?

Comment: Your XSLT looks fine. You could potentially add `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>` to it, but I don't think that would solve your problem. Can you describe how you are actually applying the XSLT to the XML please? Thank you.

Comment: It's only applied as much as you're seeing here. Like I said, I'm very new to both XML and XSL so I'm only going off of what I've looked up.

Comment: I mean, what are currently doing to produce that output? Have you written a C# program, for example, to apply the XSLT to the XML? Are you using some third party application?

Comment: I've tried a couple of different applications already, including a Java program (which wouldn't function properly on my PC) and a C# program, which printed it into a console app. But the problem is, I just want it outputted into an HTML page, not a console app.

Comment: Just to clarify, these are the options I've tried already. I'm struggling to find the thing that will do exactly what I need. I only have the XML and XSLT, and am lost on Step 3.

Comment: I guess my revised question, since I know now that my XSL is fine, is what output method SHOULD I use for a simple HTML table? I'm not familiar with all the applications out there.

Comment: Possibly you could start with using the `xml-stylesheet` directive in your XML. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456697/how-to-link-up-xml-file-with-xslt-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments of *@TimC*, you can simply add a line like

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="your.xslt" ?>
```

to your `.xml` file with the name of `your.xslt` file.
Then, in your XSLT file, you should add

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5" />
```

right after your `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Then, if you open your XML file in your browser, you should get the desired tables (and can improve their layout). Take care that both files are in the same directory.