# How to style an XML driven URL

Tags: css, xml, api

I have a URL which is using an API key and driven and displayed as XML. I have attached a screen shot as to how the information is being displayed in a browser. However, I need it to look more user friendly. Is this possible at all? The information is the details of an address book from DotMailer.
I'm rubbish at coding so an idiots guide would be great! : )

[image]

Comment: use css: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-style-an-xml-file-with-css.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending your knowledge, you have a lot of options, eg.:

- using XSL [in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456697/how-to-link-up-xml-file-with-xslt-file) or [in this way](https://opensource.com/article/18/12/xml-browser), if you could not modify the XML (you should be able to put the stylesheet directive with the xsl file there to let the browser do the transformation), you can [execute](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp) an XSLT in javascript
- using [javascript to parse the XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp), and you can generate and add the HTML version to an output div
- if your XML is generated at server side, you can use XSL too, or you can generate HTML at the server side using pure server side language (PHP, C#, Java, etc.), if you are a bit advanced, you can choose a template engine (smarty for PHP, T4 for C#, freemarker or velocity for Java, etc.), and go with it (the template engine can be an option at client side [too](https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/)), or you can stick at XSL, almost every server side language supports it.

Of course, you should create some CSS too to produce a nice output.
If you can provide some additional hint I can provide more accurate answer.