# Unable to import XSL/XSLT external stylesheet into my XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm unable to import my XSLT/XSL stylesheet into my XML, it just constantly doesn't work. I wrote the code on w3schools and it worked there as It did it for me internally, but I am unable, since putting them into two seperate documents, to get them to link.

Many ways of importing, multiple hrefs, moving the position of it.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<href="cuisinexsl.xsl" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform%22%3E" 
 xsl:stylesheetversion="1.0">

 <cuisines>
     <greek>
        <name>Food from Zeus</name>
        <address>96 Almighty Road</address>
        <phone>02 2321 5592</phone>
        <deliveryfee>Delivery fee is $7</deliveryfee>
        <URL>https://zeusfoods.com.au/</URL>
        <takeaway>Yes</takeaway>
        <dinein>Yes</dinein>
        <openhours>9-5 Mon-Sat,Sunday Closed</openhours>
        <description>Food created by us, that even the almighty would die 
         for.</description>   
     </greek>
     <greek>
        <name>Gone Greek</name>
        <address>25 Meldo Road</address>
        <phone>02 9597 5062</phone>
        <deliveryfee>Delivery fee is $10</deliveryfee>
        <URL>https://www.meetthegreek.com.au/</URL>
        <takeaway>Yes</takeaway>
        <dinein>Yes</dinein>
        <openhours>10-7 Tue-Sun,Closed Mondays</openhours>
        <description>Classic Dishes, Great Greek food and salads. 
        </description>
     </greek>
     <greek>
        <name>The 300</name>
        <address>16 Madness Road</address>
        <phone>02 4251 6182</phone>
        <deliveryfee>Delivery's not available</deliveryfee>
        <URL>https://thethreehundred.com.au/</URL>
        <takeaway>No</takeaway>
        <dinein>Yes</dinein>
        <openhours>11-9 Mon-Sun</openhours>
        <description>Enjoy our renowned dining experience.</description>
     </greek>
  </cuisines>
```

xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h1>Greek Cuisine Restaurants</h1>  
<xsl:apply-templates/>  
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="greek">
  <xsl:for-each select="cuisines/greek">
       <xsl:sort select="name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
    <p>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>  
       <xsl:apply-templates select="address"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="phone"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="deliveryfee"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="URL"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="takeaway"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="dinein"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="openhours"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="description"/>
   </p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
  Name: <span style="">
 <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
   <br />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="address">
  Artist: <span style="">
 <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
   <br />
 </xsl:template>


 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the XSL to import into the XML and display the way it's meant to instead of a big clump. I deleted most of the template matches to save space when linking this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link up XML file with XSLT file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456697/how-to-link-up-xml-file-with-xslt-file)

Comment: The first line of your XML needs to be `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cuisinexsll"?>` (with the existing `<href="cuisinexsl.xsl" ....` needing to be removed)