# How to prepend an xml declaration and processing instructions to an XQuery result?

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, basex, flwor

How is the result of an XQuery prepended with an xml declaration, and a line linking it to an xslt?

error:

```
Stopped at /home/nicholas/git/xml/labs.xq, 8/6:
[XPST0003] Processing instruction has illegal name: xml.
```

query:

```
xquery version "3.1";


for $doc in db:open("covid")

return 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="labs.xsl"?>

$doc
```

so that the result is ready to be used with an xslt.  Perhaps placing the declaration and "linking" line of xml outside of the query?

see also:

[How to link up XML file with XSLT file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3456697/4531180)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML declaration can only be output by a serialization option you can declare with e.g.

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'xml';
```

there is no XML declaration as a node in the XQuery data model.

A processing instruction is a node and can be constructed and prepended for instance with

```
for $doc in db:open("covid")
return 
  (<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="labs.xsl"?>, $doc)
```

or perhaps cleaner or more explicitly with

```
for $doc in db:open("covid")
return 
document {
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="labs.xsl"?>,
  $doc/node()
}
```

Comment: To hammer this home, **the XML declaration is not a processing instruction** in the XDM data model. It's lexically similar to a processing instruction, but that's where the resemblance ends. The way you generate an XML declaration is by setting the right serialization options for the query result, in particular `omit-xml-declaration=no` if that isn't already the default. By contrast, the `<?xml-stylesheet...?>` is a processing instruction node in the result tree and is constructed by evaluating a constructor expression in the query.